# Boolean checkbox needs to be accepted all the time even when checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I've put a validation in a checkbox for tos_agreements, but now, even if it's checked, it still gives me the error "Tos Agreements need to be accepted".

What I have is:

1.) I've added :tos_agreements to Devise permitted params in Application Controller

2.) I've validated like this:

`validates_acceptance_of :tos_agreement, :allow_nil => false, :accept => true`

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: i think you add the value, but not to the db, so is trying to save the record, but the attribute is not existence, anyway i leave an answer on how to achieve this, regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually do this with an attr_accessor(*of course in the model of the user*):

```
attr_accessor :tos_agreement
validates :tos_agreement, acceptance: true
```

this will validate that the checkbox tos_agreement will be checked, *regards*